# visual studio thinks incorrct my correct sql query

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

one problem is killing me.
what is the problem with this code:

```
        string id = Request["ids"];
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(helper.conn);
        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select id  from Person where Id        in      (" + id + ")", con);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
        da1.Fill(ds1);
        con.Open();
        com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //gdvusers.DataSource = ds1;
        //gdvusers.DataBind();
        con.Close();

        rpt_print.DataSource = ds1;
        rpt_print.DataBind();
```

visual studio 2013 says incorrect syntax near','

Comment: What is in the ID variavble?

Comment: may be your string id contains comma , at last .

Comment: ids from previous page

Comment: what the value of string id variable?

Comment: What a confidence LOL, "Visual Studio Thinks Incorrect" LOL, do you think VS is a person who is having some personal problem with you!! Amazing thought.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think ID's may be something like : "3,4,9,8,"
Notice the last commma?

It can throw off the statement

Comment: not exactly,but it was good advise,because the problem was from string id,thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be your `string id` trailing with comma , at last, so try this

```
string id = Request["ids"].ToString().TrimEnd(',',' ');
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(helper.conn);
SqlCommand com1 = 
     new SqlCommand("select id  from Person where Id in (" + id + ")", con);
```

Comment: not exactly,but it was good advise,because the problem was from string id,thank you

Comment: so what was the value of id?